# Mixpanel alias, identify and initpushnotifications on Android

Tags: android, mixpanel

The ideal mixpanel implementation says:

1. Call `alias` once upon sign up
2. Call `identify` upon log in

In another place I read that we shouldn't call alias and identify one after another.
However, the push notificatsions page for Mixpanel says that we should:

1. Call `identify`
2. Call `initPushNotifications`

so now, in my Android app, the `alias` is called right after user sign up, and then in order to setup push notifications, I have to call `identify`.

I don't know what to do because this doesn't work unless I skip `alias` but if I do, I can't track the events that happened before sign up

btw I call `alias` and `identify` by passing my app's unique server ID that I use everywhere - is that the way it should be?

also, should I call `mixpanelApi.identify()` and then `mixpanelApi.getPeople().identify()` or can I only call one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely call `identify()` after calling `alias()`.

I think it won't work the other way around.

So, On user register:

Call alias -> Identify -> initPushNotification

Comment: this is what I am currently doing, but the $android_devices property that enables me to send push notifications doesnt get recorded for that user in mixpanel but it gets recorded for another user created with the mixpanel distinct id instead. When I remove the alias call, the $android_devices property gets associated with the mixpanel user that uses my app's eternal unique id which is good, but then I lose the events that happened before registration

Comment: Did you call identify on both MixPanelAPI and on the People instance?

Comment: yes. should i? btw the mixpanel support person told me that "if you use alias immediately, it might create a race condition on the server" - something along those lines. so after alias I call flush, then I wait for 10 seconds before doing identify. But this didnt work out too

Comment: Ok. I'm not doing any of this. I'm just calling `alias(newId, oldId)` first, Then `mixPanelApi.identify(newId)` and `people.identify(newId)` in that order. Finally, I call `people.initPushNotifications()`. Works for me.

Comment: what do you pass as `newid` and `oldid` in alias? I pass my own app id as new id and null as old id. Do you call flush inbetween?

Comment: It's ok to pass null as old Id, it just maps it to the current id (which is mixPanel random generated id). I don't call flush anywhere.